# Aem Magento integration, aem orders are not showing in magento

Tags: magento, aem

I have installed the connector in Aem6.4 as well as in Magento2.2 and i fetched the magento products in aem. but when i am adding aem product into cart it's not showing magento checkout iframe. and while placing the order from aem, order is not showing in magento.

Comment: Welcome SO. Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you install any magento extesion or you customization anything in magento2?

Comment: i installed the module provided here https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/deploying/using/magento.html